# Como criar Toolbar customizada igual a do ACMarket

Tags: android, android-layout

Quero criar uma `Toolbar` igual a do ACMarket, mas não pretendo usar `CollapsingToolbar`, quero apenas criar uma Toolbar parecida, alguém ajuda?

[image: Apenas o layout da Toolbar]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/tool" 
    android:elevation="13dp" 
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize" 
    android:background="@drawable/bg_action_bar_3" 
    app:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" 
    app:popupTheme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

O segredo é colocar **android:layout_margin="8dp"** na Toolbar. Vai funcionar em qualquer layout.

Answer (score 0):

Uma opção é colocar sua barra de ferramentas  [**`Toolbar`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) dentro de um [**`CardView`**](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html?hl=pt-br), sendo assim para distanciar um pouco da borda, é necessário usar a propriedade `layout_margin` definindo-a o valor que achar melhor. Abaixo segue um exemplo utilizando elevação do `CardView` em `8dp`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/map_toolbar_container"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/whatever_you_want"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#324">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/wld_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

#### Imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]